# Named Entity Recognition using context of the sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science-model, nltk

I have a problem in which I want to know how can we extract or name the entity based on the context in which it is getting used in a sentence.

For example: 
If we have to extract date field which is used in the context of the date of birth only then how can we do that.

I know that we can use regular expression, spacy, NLTK to extract date field from a document. But I am unable to determine the approach to extract date based on the context in which it is getting used.

Comment: Cam you add few examples ?

Comment: Example 1 : My birthday is on 9th December. Here 9th December will be marked as date field if we use spacy or regex, but I want it to be marked as a custom entity 'date of birth'.
Example 2: I am going for a movie on 1st April. Here 1st April should be marked as normal date field.